# Cannot read next data for the dataset error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am looking to return data between Date1 and Date2 using parameters in SSRS. The table I am selecting from is a DB2 table which is linked on a SQL Instance 
(slow I know).

Here's my query:

```
SELECT ACC_NBR
      ,SYST_DT
      ,NBR_CHK
      ,CHK_TOT  
FROM [DB].[DB].[DB2].[TAB]
WHERE SYST_DT BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

> **ERROR:**
> A failure occurred while giving parameter information to OLE DB
>   provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "MYlinkedServer".
>   ---------------------------- Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DB2Table. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
>   ---------------------------- An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

Please could anyone assist me? I have also updated linked server connection to `;Derive Parameters=TRUE;`. Didn't seem to help.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/WindowsServer/en-US/e86e614f-de46-48f3-b9a8-fbd1c8102b35/cannot-read-the-next-data-row-for-the-data-set?forum=sqlreportingservices